# Getting the count of a table inside a factory in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-seeding, laravel-factory

I'm making a quiz app in Laravel, but I'm having a little trouble.

I have two tables in the database, questions and answers (questions has a title and an image, and answers has an answer, correct field and question_id) and I'm making the seeders for them in Laravel. I want to make it so a question has only 3 answers and only one correct, so I tried to do something like this in the answer factory (it's a little messy because I was trying stuff around):

```
    $idEncontrado = false;
    $questionId = Question::inRandomOrder()->first()->id;
    $answers = Answer::where("question_id", $questionId)->get();

    while ($idEncontrado == false){
        if(count($answers) < 3){
            $idEncontrado = true;
        }else{
            $questionId = Question::inRandomOrder()->first()->id;
            $answers = Answer::where("question_id", $questionId)->get();
        }
    }

    return [
        'answer' => $this->faker->paragraph("2"),
        'correct' => function () use ($questionId, $answers) {
            $correcta = false;
            if(count($answers) == 0){
                $correcta = true;
            }
            return $correcta;
        },
        "question_id" => $questionId,
    ];
```

After trying to do this for a while I found out that it seems that the count I'm doing for the answer always return 0 for some reason, so nothing works as intended.
I know I can do this manually if I really wanted to, but now that I spent a little while trying to fix this I want to know if there is a way to do it.
Thank you.

Comment: You get a random "questionId", get its "answers", then if the answers count is less than 3, you get another random questionId and get all of its answers  then if the answers count is less than 3, you get another random questionId and get all of its answers and so on ...
If you want to randomly find the record in your DB that already has 3 answers you are on the correct path.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that for some reason the count($answers) I do always return a 0, so the logic doesn't work

Comment: You need to first create a question and inside the while loop just create your answers.